# Validity of CliftonStrengths

Tags: psychology, test

Trying to find information about the validity of CliftonStrengths.
For a commercial, restricted test (which perhaps is not classified as test by the owner) it can be hard to find independent verification/opinions, and even this question might attract some interest from the owner company :)

There's an [older question about longitudinal validity](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/24441/longitudinal-consistency-of-strengthsfinder) and [some](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/dont-drink-strengths-based-kool-aid-towards-science-ron-warren/) [criticism](https://web.archive.org/web/20220725190301/https://danspira.com/2009/01/10/top-five-weaknesses-of-strengthsfinder/).
[RAND has some studies listed](https://www.rand.org/education-and-labor/projects/assessments/tool/1999/clifton-strengthsfinder.html), but the most recent is from 2007 and comes from the owner of the tool.

What would be the most recent studies on the validity (internal consistency, test-retest, factors - anything) of this tool? External and peer reviewed studies preferred.